# Scope values aren't displayed when getting HTML from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**UPDATE**
After doing many tests on my code I'm updating my previous question, as it's now clearer to me what's not working.

1. My HTML file is served when I browse to the / directory in my local
2. All the pages loads nicely except for the content of the $scope in my directives (see below).
3. I've tested loading the page directly (just clicked on the html file) and I can see the content.

I'm not sure where the problem is. 
I've removed all un-necessary lines from the HTML file to give a better pictures of my code. the {{}} is just the templating engine language.

**HTML**

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/text.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-  alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-  AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi"   crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js">    </script><!-- Tether for Bootstrap --> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap --> 

</head>
<body >

<h3>Select some text </h3>
<div ng-controller="Controller">
{% for i in result %}
<div id={{i._id}} class="task" commentId = {{i._id}} get-popover- content>{{i.text}} </div>
<div id={{i._id}} class="task" commentId = {{i._id}} my-customer="customer">{{i.text}} </div> 
<br/>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<script>
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.customer = {
     name: 'Naomi',
     address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
   };
 }])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
return {
  scope: {
    myCustomer: '='
  },
template: 'Name: {{myCustomer.name}} Address:         {{myCustomer.address}}'
  };

});
})(window.angular);
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround with

```
{{%  raw %}} ... {{% endraw %}}
```

Comment: Can you explain more please? i'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: in the doc for nunjucks to let the angularjs {{}} not get eaten up as nunjucks markup it says to surround html to be left untouched with raw tags

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `isolated scope` to the `directive` as below with the same name as a `directive` name,

```
scope: {
         myCustomer: '='
      }
```

and link the controller's `$scope.customer` to this `isolated scope` as below,

```
<div ... my-customer="customer"></div>
```

And change your template to access the same like this,

```
template: 'Name: {{myCustomer.name}} Address: {{myCustomer.address}}'
```

**Working sample**:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h3>Select some text </h3>
<div ng-controller="Controller">

<div id="test1" class="task" commentId="test1" get-popover-content>{{i.text}} </div>
<div id="test2" class="task" commentId="test2" my-customer="customer">{{i.text}} </div> 
<br/>

</div>

<script>
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.customer = {
  name: 'Naomi',
  address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
 };
 }])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
return {
  scope: {
     myCustomer: '='
  },
  template: 'Name: {{myCustomer.name}} Address: {{myCustomer.address}}'
};
});
  
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['docsSimpleDirective']);
})(window.angular);
  
</script>
  
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried it. it prints the 'Name' and the 'Address" and not their values.

Comment: @AmirA.Eitan If you click "Run code snippet" on my answer above you can see the values. I assume you may be done something wrong. Can you edit your question with what you tried and I can have a look to fix the code. Can you edit your question?

Comment: I've copied the entire HTML code, in case it helps. Thank you!

Comment: @AmirA.Eitan In your html, you have like this `my-customer customer="customer"`, can you change this to `my-customer="customer"`  and remove this `<my-customer customer="customer"></my-customer>`? Looks like you have mixed two answers.

Comment: Like this, `<div id={{i._id}} class="task" commentId = {{i._id}} my-customer="customer"> {{i.text}} </div>`

Comment: And remove this `<my-customer customer="customer"></my-customer>`

Comment: I tried it but still... the scope is not printing out.

Comment: Can you edit the question again by copying the same content you tried? There may be a minor thing missed out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130351/discussion-between-amir-a-eitan-and-aruna).

Comment: Can you post the output it prints as it is

Comment: I've posted in the chat

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `scope: { .... }` inside directive to access your controller scope
**Controller**

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.customer = {
  name: 'Naomi',
  address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
 };
 }])
```

**HTML**

```
// use this directive and pass customer to the directive scope
<my-customer customer="customer"></my-customer>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
   return {
       scope: {
            customer: '=customer'
              }
       template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
   };
 });
```

Comment: I have tried it. it prints the 'Name' and the 'Address" and not their values.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better pattern for what you're trying to achieve (note the comment for an API call for your customers in JSON format).

Calling for the data via API after the page has loaded will allow you to keep your HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT as totally static files (no templating engine etc) and decoupled from your data.

It will load faster and give you the option to host your web front-end entirely on something like a CDN (which frees up your API server to focus only on requests for data/ sessions stuff like that).

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
  <head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/text.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi"   crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js">    </script><!-- Tether for Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap -->

  </head>
  <body>

    <h3>Select some text</h3>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <!-- not sure what 'id' or 'text' values are, you should pass them in
          via API if they are needed -->
        <div id={{i._id}} class="task" commentId = {{i._id}} get-popover- content>{{i.text}} </div>
        <div id={{i._id}} class="task" commentId = {{i._id}} my-customer="customer">{{i.text}} </div>
        <br/>
      </div >
    </div>

    <script>
      (function(angular) {
        'use strict';

        angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
        .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

          // make a request to api to get customers in JSON format

          // assign result to scope.customers
          $scope.customers= [
            {
              name: 'Naomi',
              address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
            },
            {
              name: 'Amir',
              address: '58 W 54th st'
            }
          ];

        }])
        .directive('myCustomer', function() {
          return {
            scope: {
              myCustomer: '='
            },
            template: 'Name: {{myCustomer.name}} Address: {{myCustomer.address}}'
          };
        }); // directive
      })(window.angular);

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

you can also mock a REST API server by making a request to a static file like this:

```
 $http.get("./myFakeAPI.json").then(function(response){
  $scope.customers = response.data.customers;
});
```

where the contents of the file 'myFakeAPI.json' is:

```
{
  "customers":
    [
      {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
      },
      {
        name: 'Amir',
        address: '58 W 54th st'
      }
    ]
}
```